# Compile and start java file in bash without saving compiled file

Tags: java, bash

Is it possible to compile and run a java file in bash without saving the compiled file?
I'm using the command `javac File.java && java File`. It works but it creates a `File.class` file.

Can I somehow pipe the compiled file to the java command? I have tried `javac File.java | java` but it does not work.

Comment: Could you explain the use case for this approach?

Comment: @StefanFreitag Thanks for your comment. The reason why I wanted to do this is that I don't want to have useless files in my file system and I thought there would be an easier way than deleting it everytime.

Comment: You can compile java code within a running JVM then load the compiled class and run it. see: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compile-Java-program-B-from-inside-Java-program-A-without-calling-javac-via-Runtime-exec

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this is not possible, and it also doesn't make much sense.

You see, your JVM comes with many megabytes of precompiled classes; and many of them will be loaded while running your small class. There is no point in saving the 1 K or whatever your File.class consumes on disk space.

So you should step back and re-think what kind of problem you think you can solve by such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
javac File.java && java File ; rm File.class
```

Comment: this. although like above I gotta ask "Why?"

Would you compile /bin/bash every time you needed to start a shell process?